# Send-MailMessage does not work when sending .zip file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to send a mail using `Send-MailMessage`, the problem is that it does not deliver attachments in `zip` format. However when I try sending other files like `csv` or `html` it works fine and the email is delivered.

Maybe firewall or outlook is blocking it? Does anyone have any suggestion or idea to get this working?

I have also tried sending smtp command and the result is the same. It does not send mail having `zip` as an attachment but with other file formats, it works fine.

Comment: What command are you actually using and is there any error message or similar? Does your mail client tell you it's a blocked attachment?

Comment: please post the code. Secondly, if your internal firewall is blocking it then how can you expect to send a zipped content. probably you have to use diff format.maybe you can try with rar

Comment: `  $SMTPSRV ="10.10.10.10"
        $EmailFrom ="test@test.com"
        $EmailTo =@("Javed.Eqbal@test.com";"rajesh.narwal@test.com")
        $EmailSubject="Health Check Report"
        $EmailAttachment= $destination
        Send-MailMessage -smtpServer $SMTPSRV -from $EmailFrom -to $EmailTo -subject $EmailSubject -Attachments $EmailAttachment `

Comment: @JavedEqbal Code doesn't work well in comments, you need to click the edit link underneath your question and update it with your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folder contained files like .html , .js , .css . so I tried sending a mail with .html files and .txt files and it worked meaning the files were being blocked .

Found a workaround however . Double zipping the folder allows it to be sent on mail ;)